# Algorithm/Java program for how to calculate intersection area for n overlapping rectangles where n>2

Tags: java, algorithm, math, pseudocode, shapes

How to calculate the common area/intersection area between n no of overlapping rectangles, i'm getting logic for 2 rectangles but confused with n rectangles

Comment: Please provide your attempt and where it has gone wrong. See [mcve].

Comment: The intersection of two rectangles is still a rectangle. So, this is a recursive problem. If you got the logic for two, apply it and then take the result and apply with the following one, and so on.

Comment: You should also precise if you want the common intersection of all the rectangles (if it exists), the sum of the intersections of rectangles (where parts of intersections can be counted more than once), or the area formed by all the intersections. These are different results. @EddeAlmeida it's not necessarily a rectangle, it depends on the angle or rotation of the rectangles

Comment: Are the rectangles aligned with your coordinate system (as would be common on a computer display)? Or can they be turned to any angle?

Comment: You are right, @Kaddath. I saw the problem in a very simplistic way. I was considering only rectangles with sides aligned with cartesian axis. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Kaddath, thanks for replying. I want the sum of intersection of each reactangle with others and intersection of all rectangles only once. all the rectangles are lying on a fixed plane i.e. there is no angle of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

### naive solution:

This is maybe not the most effective/optimal solution, but it's quite easy to understand

You've got the logic for 2 rectangles intersection. This intersection is itself a rectangle. If you want to calculate the intersection with a third rectangle, calculate the intersection between the third rectangle and the rectangle made by the intersection of the previous two rectangles

### Edit:

as @Kaddath said in a comment, this solution only work if the rectangles are aligned, as otherwise it can be another shape

Comment: A simple optimization is to stop early when the resulting rectangle becomes empty

Answer (score 1):

Find the rightmost left edge of any of the rectangles. This is the left edge of the resulting intersection, which also will be a rectangle. Do similarly for the other three sides.

Remember to take the special case into consideration: There may not be any intersection. This happens if any rectangle has a right edge to the left of the calculated left edge, or any rectangle has a bottom higher than the calculated top of the result.

I have assumed that the rectangles are aligned with your coordinate system (as would be common on a computer display). If they can be turned to any angle, it’s a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
R1 ∩ R2 ∩ R3 = ( (R1 ∩ R2) ∩ R3)
```

you already know how to do intersection of two rectangles.

Comment: this will only give me intersection of all 3 rectangles, I need the sum of common areas in between them also: i.e. R1∩R2+R2∩R3+R3∩R1+R1∩R2∩R3.... so, I need more generalised version for n reactangles to develop a java program